# I can't add automatically a user ID to it's creation - Symfony 5

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, symfony5

So, there's my problem : I want to create a pet profile in my project, everything was working fine until I wanted to add some elementary information, the property User ( The user who created that profile)

I want to add the current User's ID but I'm stuck...

First, there is my Error alert:

> Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request
> information for parameter "user".

And then, there is my code on Animal.php:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="ownedAnimal", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * @param User $user
 * @return Animal
 */
public function setUser(User $user): Animal
{
    $this->user = $user->getId();
    return $this;
}
```

And in my User.php :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Animal::class, inversedBy="user")
 */
private $ownedAnimal;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->ownedAnimal = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Animal[]
 */
public function getOwnedAnimal(): Collection
{
    return $this->ownedAnimal;
}

public function addOwnedAnimal(Animal $ownedAnimal): self
{
    if (!$this->ownedAnimal->contains($ownedAnimal)) {
        $this->ownedAnimal[] = $ownedAnimal;
        $ownedAnimal->setUser($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeOwnedAnimal(Animal $ownedAnimal): self
{
    if ($this->ownedAnimal->removeElement($ownedAnimal)) {
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($ownedAnimal->getUser() === $this) {
            $ownedAnimal->setUser(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So, when I try to submit the registration of a new Animal, I got this error above... It seems dumb but I can't find a solution...

Please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that inside the controller in add function because inside the controller you can have an access to the current user:

```
public function create()
{ 
   $animal = new Animal();
   // .......

   if($fom->isSubmitted() && $fom->isValid())
   {
      $animal->setUser($this->getUser());
      // persit and flush
   }

}
```

Comment: Men! You are a life savor!!! It worked, thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

Your user property should be an instance of User. You should set a user to it not a user id.

This sould work.

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @return Animal
 */
public function setUser(User $user): Animal
{
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I should've specified that I tried that :/ Thank you for taking the time to help me ^^

Comment: But it seemd that my code was more profoundly broken, I tried to login in my project and I had a lot of other problems that I didn't notice when I first posted. So I made a git reset, I will probably encounter a problem like this one later today. Thanks again friend